# Hiding get mobile app button on sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have tried the guide here: https://github.com/n8design/whitespace but the application customiser does not seem to be working for me.

I edited the config like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.micnpm -v
  rosoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "serveConfigurations": {
    "default": {
      "pageUrl": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/SitePages/Home.aspx",
      "customActions": {
        "78478cf9-373a-4b36-950c-ce02224fc0c3": {
          "location": "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer",
          "properties": {
            "testMessage": "Test message",
            "CSSOverrideUrl": "https://n8design.github.io/whitespace/blacklist.css"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "n8DWhiteSpace": {
      "pageUrl": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/SitePages/Home.aspx",
      "customActions": {
        "78478cf9-373a-4b36-950c-ce02224fc0c3": {
          "location": "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer",
          "properties": {
            "testMessage": "Test message",
            "CSSOverrideUrl": "https://n8design.github.io/whitespace/blacklist.css"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anybody got a fix for this or know or another guide?

Comment: Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270849/hiding-get-mobile-app-button-on-sp-online-communication-site-collection/270851#270851) for easy solution. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Where do I put that CSS in your answer? @GaneshSanap This is an an option for me: Set-SPOTenant -UserVoiceForFeedbackEnabled $false

Comment: You can use [Modern script editor webpart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to add your CSS on homepage.

Comment: Thank you. Will this app take up screen space on my page? @GaneshSanap

Comment: Yes, you can access any HTML element to show/hide from entire page where the webpart is added.

Comment: The web part looks like it is placed on the page though. Will it be visible by the users? The web part? @GaneshSanap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101875/discussion-between-bennkingy-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding get mobile app button on SP online communication site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270849/hiding-get-mobile-app-button-on-sp-online-communication-site-collection)

Comment: My answer at the bottom does (; @MP_89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://kaboodlesoftware.com/products/framework-solutions-for-sharepoint-modern/kaboodle-branding-package/ <<<< There is a web part on this page which removes the buttons! And allows easy customation of the site with css/html/javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below CSS to hide get mobile app button from a page:

```
a[aria-label^='Get the mobile app'] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Or

```
div[class^='feedback_'] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Note**: You can use [Modern script editor webpart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to add your CSS on homepage.

For more details check my answer given at: [Hiding get mobile app button on SP online communication site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270849/hiding-get-mobile-app-button-on-sp-online-communication-site-collection/270851#270851)